# Sympy piecewise functions - Defining a single domain point

Tags: python-3.x, sympy, symbolic-math, piecewise

Executing the below code in Sympy 1.11.1 returns `NaN`.

```
from sympy import *
x = Symbol("x", real=True)
p = Piecewise((0, x < 0), (0, x > 0), (1, x == 0))
p.subs(x,0)

>>>> nan
```

I expected the result to be `1`. What is happening here, and is there a workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Print out your expressions to see the problem:

```
In [1]: from sympy import *
   ...: x = Symbol("x", real=True)
   ...: p = Piecewise((0, x < 0), (0, x > 0), (1, x == 0))
   ...: p.subs(x,0)
Out[1]: nan

In [2]: p
Out[2]: {0  for x > 0 ∨ x < 0

In [3]: x == 0
Out[3]: False

In [4]: Eq(x, 0)
Out[4]: x = 0

In [5]: p2 = Piecewise((0, x < 0), (0, x > 0), (1, Eq(x, 0)))

In [6]: p2
Out[6]: 
⎧0  for x > 0 ∨ x < 0
⎨                    
⎩1      for x = 0    

In [7]: p2.subs(x, 0)
Out[7]: 1
```

The problem is that `x == 0` in sympy is for structural equality i.e. it is for checking whether two expressions are syntactically identical. To create a symbolic boolean expressing the symbolic condition that `x` is equal to zero you need to use `Eq(x, 0)`.